# Ajuda com front-end, parte responsiva

Tags: html, css

fala pessoal, tudo bem? preciso de uma ajuda, estou fazendo uma página de login e na minha máquina está tudo alinhado, dentro das divs corretamente, porém em outros pc's está ficando quebrada a formatação, alguem poderia me dar uma luz do que posso estar fazendo para resolver esse problema?

Esse é o código da box onde estão as infos da página
[![

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 700px;
    height: 85vh;
    padding: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    border-radius: 5px;   
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tira o valor de altura do .box pra testar

Comment: Qual o problema? Só olhando os prints fica difícil adivinhar o problema. Vc descrevendo o problema facilita mais e vc pode obter a solução ao seu problema mais facilmente. Em qual resolução ficou "quebrado" (onde está quebrado?)? É bom colocar o código completo também par que possamos tentar reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Como falaram você não colocou o código de tudo. Seria bom colocar em algum lugar para realmente testar e te ajudar.

No olho assim vou tentar com o que entendo que pode estar errado.

1- Tira o height: 85vh; Você colocou uma altura fixa então os elementos vão ser distribuídos dentro desse contexto.

2- Setar um margin e padding para todos os elementos filhos

```css
.box > * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

os navegadores vem com espaço entre os elementos diferentes entre um , ,  e etc então você pode setar um valor para cada elemento.

Segue o link do site do cara mais bacana que conheço sobre essa solução: 
[https://www.maujor.com](https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/pseudoclasses-para-elementos-filhos.php)

Se quiser ajudar quem pode te ajudar colocar o HTML junto com o CSS aqui ou em algum site de tipo [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Ou no seu github

E ao infinito e além.

Comment: Pastebin não! O código deve ficar aqui na página na forma de um [mcve] e a resposta deve ser baseada estritamente sobre o conteúdo da pergunta.